# Available counters in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

We are trying to pinpoint some memory issues, and for that we would need additional counters in our app-insight Analytics data, the counters which would help us nail the issue would be

```
\Memory\Page Faults /sec
\Memory\Page Reads /sec
\Memory\Cache Faults /sec
\Memory\Available Bytes
\Paging File(*)\% Usage Peak
\Process(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Working Set Peak
\Process(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Working Set - Private
```

If I add this counter in my ApplicationInisights.config I receive message

AI: Performance counter is not available in the web app supported list. Counter is $CounterName

So it seams that process does not have permissions to get the performance counters.

I have following questions :

- How can I add counter `Process Page Faults` to `applicationinishgts.config` so that it gets stored into analytics portal (I tried this `\Memory(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Page Faults /sec` but it did not work). It is shown in Live Matrics Stream so it is possible
- Would it help if I would try to give permissions to WWW-process on startup using powershell or similar?  or this just will not work (not implemented / by design ..)
- Is there a list of performance counters which can be used in Azure Web App ?
- In Live Stream - Process CPU (sum of % across all cores) is shown (but can not be changed), this is obviously global counter - as  the above counters are extremely useful could those be added in similar way somehow?

Comment: the counters you have access to at runtime really depend on how and where you are deploying your app.  have you run through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters ?  it has some things you *might* be able to do to check which perfcounters you can see

Comment: as stated in title - I need those for "Azure Web App"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application Insights has ability to collect a sub-set of counters when running inside Azure WebApps. There is no documentation of the supported list, but here's the code.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/4093e9a6d350a9d4759eb64a2be17a90dc23f85a/Src/PerformanceCollector/Perf.Shared.NetFull/Implementation/WebAppPerformanceCollector/CounterFactory.cs#L21

Any counter not listed above will not be collected in Web Apps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but App Service has a not-well-advertised feature that lets you get at some of the perf counters by evaluating some special environment variables:

- WEBSITE_COUNTERS_ASPNET
- WEBSITE_COUNTERS_APP
- WEBSITE_COUNTERS_CLR
- WEBSITE_COUNTERS_ALL

See this [wiki page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Perf-Counters-exposed-as-environment-variables) for more info.

It's not something that App Insights would consume right now (as far as I know), but presumably they could add support for it in the future.

Comment: can I get access to those somehow in app-insights ? and get those values  to app-insights-analytics portal ?

Comment: Probably not automatically, but you could add code that reads those and explicitely logs what you care about to App Insights.

Comment: could you send me a link where I could get more info? and start implementation

Comment: ApplicationInsights SDK already uses these special EnvironmentVariables exposed in WebApp for perf counters.

Comment: @cijothomas good to hear! I guess we probably exposed them for you :)